# Running a server with Ansible

Tags: ansible

I just started using Ansible and I am having trouble running a server.

I have a server which can be started using `java -jar target/server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`. However, this will start the server and keep running forever displaying output, so Ansible never finishes.

This is what I tried that never finishes:

```
- name: Start server
  command: chdir=~/server java -jar target/server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: You should create a startup script (which is unrelated to Ansible). An init.d script in Debian or a systemd service script in CentoOS. Then you can use the `service` module of Ansible to start/stop/restart your service.

Comment: Not a clean option: use `shell` module and put the command in the background, additionally detach from shell..

Comment: shell: nohup java -jar target/server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar &

Answer (score 3):

Either create a service, as @udondan suggests, or use an asynchronous task to launch your server.  http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_async.html

Comment: async would work, but it's not, as @maeh says, the "proper" way to do it. Async tasks are great for tasks that will be done by the end of the play; using it to start a server/daemon is definitely not that.

Answer (score 2):

As @Petro026 suggested, your choices are *asynchronous task* or creating a service.

I would strongly suggest against the *asynchronous task* approach. It's a very fragile solution:

- What if the host is restarted?
- What if you run your playbook twice?
- What if your server app just dies?

Your best bet is to create a service for it, and probably the easiest approach for it would involve using a process control system like [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/), which is supported by [ansible](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/supervisorctl_module.html).

From the *supervisor* docs:

> Supervisor is a client/server system that allows its users to monitor
>   and control a number of processes on UNIX-like operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

Put that in a PID and send the output to nohup.

Something like this:

nohup java -jar target/server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar &

In your playbook:

- name: Start server
  command: chdir=~/server nohup java -jar target/server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar &

If you want kill the process kill -9 #numerofpid.